# Where can I purchase Banquete Chilero Sauce from Costa Rica in the US?

Tags: sauce, shopping, spicy-hot

I have been to Costa Rica twice and I fell in love with Banquete brand Chilero Sauce.

It is a hot sauce with a wonderful flavor but it has some fairly unique properties -- specifically that it is very similar in color and consistency / viscosity to asian sweet and sour sauces.  This lets the sauce cling in a thick layer on the food to which it is applied.

I have tried looking for this sauce but it is hard to find even by mail order in the US and the price for shipping from Costa Rica costs many times more than the sauce itself.  Apparently a lot of places carry Lizano sauce but this brand of Chilero seems to be left out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enjoyed this sauce from Costa Rica as well, and ordered it from Ticoshopping.com.  However 2 of the bottle arrived broken and the contents spilled all over the place. It would help if someone showed them how to pack items for international shipment. 12 bottles loose in a cardboard box with packing peanuts doesn't cut it.

:(

Well, I just heard back from them and they are reshipping some bottles to replace the broken bottles. So they do have GREAT customer service.

Comment: I bought some from there too.  You pretty much have to buy a dozen because it costs so much to ship the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[Costa Rica Superstore carries it](http://costaricasuperstore.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=53), though they appear to ship from Costa Rica.

I'm afraid I don't know of any stores that you can physically visit to purchase the sauce though.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ticoshopping.com/Banquete-Chilero-8-pack-55-oz

they have it! its about $16 dollars to ship!

Comment: Yeah... that's where I bought it.  I had to buy a case to make the shipping worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Costa Rican Store just got it in and is getting it added to their website.  www.CostaRicanStore.com.  The prices will be similar to the Lizano Chiero with the Free shipping Special.

[Lizano Chilero (http://costaricanstore.com/costa-rica-free-shipping-specials/lizano-salsa-sauce-free-shipping-from-costa-rica/lizano-chilero-free-shipping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has this [other brand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MOC1XG) - maybe worth a try at least for the ease of ordering.

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for the link. I don't think it's the same thing.  That's a red hot sauce and  Banquete brand Chilero Sauce is a weird orange color.  It's pretty much the exact same color and viscosity as Asian Sweet and Sour Sauce but spicy... which is awesome.

Comment: FWIW, Lizano sauce (their dark Salsa sauce) is very easy to get in the US and seems quite popular.